# style my placeholder in react select using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react select.
- I am trying to style my placeholder using css
- so I build a prototype in sandbox.
- and I tried to change the color of the placeholder using css.
- I gave the color as red, but still not overwriting
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my sandbox and code snippet below.
- even I googled for placeholder css, got this link but still not helping me

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-1q8nd

```or-tag-here
<Select
    defaultValue={""}
    label="Single select"
    placeholder={" Placeholder test "}
    options={flavourOptions}
    theme={theme => ({
      ...theme,
      borderRadius: 0,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        primary25: "hotpink",
        primary: "black",
        background: "red",
        color:"red",
      }
    })}
  />
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [react-select](https://react-select.com/styles#overriding-the-theme) docs, the neutral50 response for placeholder's color.

Try this:

```
<Select
  defaultValue={""}
  label="Single select"
  placeholder={" Placeholder test "}
  options={flavourOptions}
  theme={theme => ({
    ...theme,
    borderRadius: 0,
    colors: {
      ...theme.colors,
      neutral50: 'red',  // Placeholder color
    }
  })}
/>
```

Or you can do simply as below:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        We see that the final rendered output is not an input box, but rather a
        set of divs with certain classes applied on them... so we just change
        the class
      </p>
      <Select
        defaultValue={""}
        label="Single select"
        placeholder="Placeholder test"
        styles={colorStyles}
        options={flavourOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const colorStyles = {
  placeholder: defaultStyles => {
    return {
      ...defaultStyles,
      color: "blue"
    };
  }
};
```

Check this example: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-141ff)

Comment: hi, is it possible to fix it without theme options, since in my codebase we are not using any theme and whats the use of this number `neutral50`

Comment: I tried to solve the solution using `&::placeholder` , since the solutions which you guys is not working in code base, providing my updated code in the sandbox, can you please help https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-bv3di

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder is actually a div, so you can style it via CSS in the following way:

```
.css-1wa3eu0-placeholder {
  color: red !important;
}

p {
  color: blue;
}

.myDiv > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: orange !important;
}
```

complete [working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-ivnjn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: hi, is it possible to fix it without theme options, since in my codebase we are not using any theme and whats the use of this number `1wa3eu0`

Comment: the theme options were used in your code and got copied when I forked your example - if you do inspect element (browser developer tools), you'll see that the input is actually a div and the class on that div is named `css-1wa3eu0-placeholder` or you can traverse your way down to the exact placeholder div and apply your styling

Comment: @xoi have you looked at the complete working example that Akber provided?

Comment: I also came up with similar solutions as the two answers you have received, if they are not sufficient I would say that your questions and example code on codesandbox need to be updated.

Comment: @Akbar: I tried to solve the solution using `&::placeholder` , since the solutions which you guys is not working in code base, providing my updated code in the sandbox, can you please help https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-bv3di

Comment: in your code at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-bv3di yu had commented the color property inside the class `.css-1wa3eu0-placeholder` - just uncomment it to get it working